# ValueError: Package 'soundfile' does not exist or is not a package! on auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, auto-py-to-exe, soundfile

While converting a python programm that uses pytorch and pyaudio to .exe I´m getting "ValueError: Package 'soundfile' does not exist or is not a package!" on auto-py-to-exe even though it works fine in PyCharm and I have checked that soundfile is correctly installed.

Comment: Are you using Pyinstaller to convert the program to an executable? I had the same error using the latest version of pyinstaller (version 5.3). I resolved the issue by downgrading to version 4.10

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove SoundFile as below cmd.

pip3 uninstall SoundFile